# Where do I put custom webpart code in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm fairly new to Sharepoint, but it's vital to a current project I'm working on.

As part of the project, I need to use audience targeting to control who can see individual list entries.

I know there's no OOTB solution, but I found the following blog that looks like it's exactly what I need:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedi/archive/2012/07/31/item-level-audience-targeting-in-xsltlistviewwebpart.aspx

My problem is that being new to Sharepoint (and MS-based dev entirely), I don't know what to do with the code. I think I need to create a customer web part, is that correct?

I've Googled and checked the few sharepoint references we have but everything I can find assumes a certain level of knowledge that I just don't have with SP2010. Can anyone give me a step by step to using the above code?

Comment: Do you mean the code of the function `OnLoad`? Create a `Web Part` and there you put this function.